# Flex column layout for new vuetify API

Tags: vuetify.js

Can anyone please tell me how to adjust this code for the new vuetify syntax with rows and cols instead of v-layout and v-flex? I tried a lot but couldn't get this to work.

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid fill-height class="grey lighten-5 flex-column">
      <v-layout column no-gutters style="width: 100%">
        <v-flex xs10 class="red pa-4">
            <div class="text-h4">1st Layout</div>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex xs2 class="yellow pa-4">
            <div class="text-h4">2nd Layout</div>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

[image]
Link to codepen:
https://codepen.io/anindyamanna/pen/oNLBQbW?editable=true&editors=101%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fvuetifyjs.com%2F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `v-layout` to `v-row` then `v-flex` to `v-col` as stated in the [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/#sub-components).  <strike>I'm assuming that you want to achieve two columns that are placed side by side, occupying the whole width.</strike>

```html
<v-row style="width: 100%;" no-gutters>
  <v-col cols="10" class="red pa-4"><div class="text-h4">1st Layout</div></v-col>
  <v-col cols="2" class="yellow pa-4"><div class="text-h4">2nd Layout</div></v-col>
</v-row>
```

Since you want to place the divs on top of each other, you must add `d-flex` and `flex-column` to your `<v-row>` so that it will have a `display: flex`. Then, you need to override the max-width of the `<v-col>` to 100%;

```html
<v-row class="d-flex flex-column" style="width: 100%;" no-gutters>
  <v-col cols="10" class="red pa-4" style="max-width: 100%">
    <div class="text-h4">1st Layout</div>
  </v-col>
  <v-col cols="2" class="yellow pa-4" style="max-width: 100%">
    <div class="text-h4">2nd Layout</div>
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```

Here's a demo: https://codepen.io/blackraspberry08/pen/OJXmLpR

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But this is totally the opposite of my output. I want vertical separation. Not horizontal. :) Please check my codepen. I also added a image now to my question.

Comment: I assumed wrong, my apologies. I updated my answer now so that the two divs are on top of each other.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works. But I'm kind of confused as to why the new api requires more work and custom css solutions to do basic stuff and why it is better than the old api. For a beginner like me, the old api seems simpler to work with in this case.